# Replace Print statement calls with a custom function

Tags: regex, replace, vb6, notepad++

There is a legacy VB6 application which uses the `Print` statement to write logs all over the application. There are more than 20 thousand occurrences of `Print`. I want to write some more logging info on each `Print` call.

It can be achieved by replacing the `Print` calls with my own function. This would help in the future as well.

Some of the statements are like this:

```
Print #FileNo, Tab(1); "My Text Here";
Print #FileNo, Tab(col); Txt;
Print #FileNo, Tab(100); Format(TheDate, "DDMMMYYYY") & "    " & Variable_Name & "Field : " & Format(Field, "x")
Print #FileNo, Tab(1); Format(TheDate, "x") & " - " & TheName;
Print #FileNo, String(132, "-")
Print #FileNo, Tab(6); "SOME VALUE"; "SOME MORE VALUES";
```

Here `;` instructs Print statement not to change the line and `Tab` instructs to  position the insertion point to an absolute column number.

**Question:** How can I replace `Print` with my own function while preserving the behavior of the `Tab` and `semicolon`?

Comment: Print & the drawing functions are holdovers from Basic & have special handling baked into the compiler so you cant simply swap the statements.  You would need to crawl over the source with a regex to match prints & replace with a call you your own function.  Replace naked `;` characters with a `,` to receive them as arguments, `paramarray` will allow the variable number of them you need.

Comment: @AlexK. i was expecting the same and so i tried to replace such statements via Notepad++ using regex option, but could not create a matching regex to replace.

Comment: @bjan You can start with something like [`Print #\w+, (?:[^;\r\n]+;?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/T4EQcw/1)

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to add [regex] and [notepad++] tags **and** take at least one of the sample inputs and provide an example of the desired output. You're likely to get a regex solution that way (which I believe will need to be done in two steps if you'll only be using an editor).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thanks

Answer (score 5):

Instead of breaking a single call into multiple calls, you should make your function expect a `ParamArray` argument [as suggested by Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903789/replace-print-command-with-a-custom-function#comment96575117_54903789). Your function should look something like this:

```vb
' Remember to set the return type or change the function to a Sub.
Public Function MyPrint(fileNo As Byte, ParamArray text() As Variant) 'As SomeType
    ' Insert body here.
End Function
```

Now, let's talk about regex. To use NotePad++ only, I believe you're going to need to do it in two steps.

1. To replace the method name (`Print` to `MyPrint`), use the following pattern:

   ```regex
   Print\h+(#\w+)
   ```

   And replace with:

   ```regex
   MyPrint \1
   ```

   **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bq9Ml2/1).**
2. To replace the semicolons with commas, you can use the following pattern:

   ```regex
   (?:MyPrint #\w+\K,\h*|(?!^)\G\h*)([^;\r\n]+);?
   ```

   And replace with:

   ```regex
   , \1
   ```

   **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7vSgkx/1).**

**Sample input:**

```
Print #FileNo, Tab(1); "My Text Here";
Print #FileNo, Tab(col); Txt;
Print #FileNo, Tab(100); Format(TheDate, "DDMMMYYYY") & "    " & Variable_Name & "Field : " & Format(Field, "x")
Print #FileNo, Tab(1); Format(TheDate, "x") & " - " & TheName;
Print #FileNo, String(132, "-")
Print #FileNo, Tab(6); "SOME VALUE"; "SOME MORE VALUES";

Print #FileNo, Tab(100); "First Text"; "Second Text"
Print #FileNo, "Third Text"; "Fourth Text"
```

**Final output:**

```
MyPrint #FileNo, Tab(1), "My Text Here"
MyPrint #FileNo, Tab(col), Txt
MyPrint #FileNo, Tab(100), Format(TheDate, "DDMMMYYYY") & "    " & Variable_Name & "Field : " & Format(Field, "x")
MyPrint #FileNo, Tab(1), Format(TheDate, "x") & " - " & TheName
MyPrint #FileNo, String(132, "-")
MyPrint #FileNo, Tab(6), "SOME VALUE", "SOME MORE VALUES"

MyPrint #FileNo, Tab(100), "First Text", "Second Text"
MyPrint #FileNo, "Third Text", "Fourth Text"
```

Comment: This answer is a great help as far as replacing text with regex using Notepad++ is concerned. This also diverted me from my original question so i have removed Edit 1 and Edit 2